# Want a seperate view inside folder

Tags: sharepoint-online

This is a different question than the frequently asked one.

I have a top level folder set to a Default View and a different view set inside the folder. I require yet another view inside this folder.

To sum it all I require 3 different views in 3 levels of folder.

- Thumbnail View in Folder 1
- List View in Folder 1.1
- Thumbnail View again in Folder 1.2

Can this be done?

Comment: The third level folder contains item with any specific content type?

Comment: no. It is a picture library. 1st folder has some images and 1 folder. when you go into this folder you have list of folders and in this folder again you have thumbnailed images. The 2nd folder is a custom content type new ordered folder

Comment: I had to show different views for 2 levels, they were just items and folder content type. I followed this https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/harness-sharepoint-default-views-at-different-navigation-hierarchy-levels-to-build-more-appealing-solutions/ and ultimately made a PowerShell script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new content types basd on Folder parent content type for Folders 1.1 (List View) and 1.2 (Thumbnail View).

Add those content types to your picture library, and change in properties of folder 1.1 default content type to "List View" content type and in 1.2 folder to "Thumbnail View" content type.

Then create a view you want and select to show this view in folder with content type your created. One view for one "List view" and one for "Thumbnail view".

[image: show this view in folder of content type]

(this option will not be grayed out then you add those folder content types)